# Moving files to different linux directory

Tags: c, linux, directory

I'm writing a small program to organize a directory in linux by creating new directories and storing files in them based on file type. I understand I need to use the `rename()` function, but how can I continue to move files with varying names?

Say if I had a `.mkv` file in my directory. My program detects the file type and move the file into a directory called `video` (within the directory I am currently working in). How can I pass the name of the file so that when the file is moved it keeps its name?

Below is my best guess as to how it should work but obviously does not compile. How can I replicate it in a way that will compile?

I already have a loop to run through `readdir()`, and within each cycle it detects the file type of each entry and uses that file type to move the file into another directory, so the `rename()` is being called inside of an if statement inside of the `readdir()` loop.

```
DIR *d; 
struct dirent *dp; 
d = opendir(".");
//if statement with function to find file type
//if the file is an .mkv, it runs: 
rename(dp->d_name, "./video/%s", dp->d_name);
//how can I do this in a way that will compile?
```

EXAMPLE:
If I had a file called `scarface.mkv`, It will create a directory `video` (already done) and move `scarface.mkv` into the `video` directory.

Comment: You cannot pass *format specifiers* to `rename` (e.g. `%s` makes no sense in `rename`). Use `sprintf` or `snprintf` to build the `newpath` for `scarface.mkv` and pass the concatenated string to`rename`. The prototype for `rename` is `int rename(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);` It's up to you to create properly *nul-terminated* `oldpath` and `newpath`. (`man 2 rename` is your friend)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not supply the whole relevant piece of code? You are not initializing dp here, but you are using it in the rename call.

rename takes 2 arguments, both of which are pointers to strings (i.e. array of characters). Your code uses 3.

%s looks like a format string, but you are not expanding this with e.g. sprintf and an additional argument to replace %s.

Comment: I know that my rename is incorrect. I am trying to show you what I am attempting to do, which is creating a directory with the name that I have stored in the "dp->d_name" variable.

Comment: You should probably stat() the directory, and if it doesn't exist mkdir() it

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment, where most new C programmers get confused is in failing to think through the whole problem at hand. You simply cannot expect to call `rename` and have it take care of the entire process. The C library functions generally do one thing, and one thing only. It is up to the programmer to think though the process from start to finish and code all additional pieces of the puzzle not provided by the `rename` or `readdir` functions.

For example, if you plan on passing a *new directory name*, you need to **validate** that the directory you intend to move files too, does in fact exist (or you need to create it). How do you test for the existence of the new directory? You also need to determine and **validate** the format for the new directory you will `rename` files to. Does it contain a trailing `'/'` or not? How do I handle it if it does?

If you only want to move files with a specific *extension*, you must develop a way to check for and obtain the extension from each filename returned by `readdir`. Once I have the extension for the current file, how do I compare it to the target extension?

Finally, how do I combine the directory name I intend to move matching files to, with the current filename to create the full path to move the files to? All of these are bits of code you need to provide to be able to move files from one directory to another. Is it hard to do? No. It's quite easy, but you have to think through it at that level and provide a minimum amount of **validation** to determine success/failure of any individual file you intend to move.

Rather than going though how to create each individual piece of the puzzle, because I understand you need help, and it does help to have a reasonable "go-by" to help cement the various pieces of the puzzle in your mind, the following is a short example that accomplishes what I understand your question is asking. The following takes the directory to search as the *first* argument, the *extension* to search for as the *second* argument, and the *relative* or *absolute* pathname to move any matching files to as the *third* argument (the defaults are `.` (search current dir) for filenames with `"mkv"` extensions, and move to the `video` subdirectory):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>     /* PATH_MAX */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* opendir  */
#include <dirent.h>     /* opendir, readdir */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno */
#include <fcntl.h>      /* for file constants */
#include <unistd.h>     /* open/close */

int dir_exists (char *d);
char *fn_ext (char *fn);
char *fn_wext (char *s);
char *stripfwd (char *fn);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    DIR *dp = opendir (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".");/* open directory (. default)*/
    struct dirent *de = NULL;                    /* ptr to dirent for readdir */
    char *srchext = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "mkv",  /* extension to search for   */
        *newdir = argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "./video",/* ptr newdir (video default)*/
        path[PATH_MAX] = "";                     /* array for trimmed newdir  */

    strcpy (path, newdir);    /* copy newdir from read-only memory to array   */
    stripfwd (path);          /* check for trailing '/' & overwrite with '\0' */
    if (!dir_exists (path)) { /* validate new directory exists */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: directory not found '%s'.\n", path);
        return 0;             /* or create/validate directory here */
    }

    while ((de = readdir (dp))) /* for each file in directory */
    {
        char *ext = NULL;

        /* skip dot files */
        if (!strcmp (de->d_name, ".") || !strcmp (de->d_name, ".."))
            continue;

        if ((ext = fn_ext (de->d_name)) == NULL)  /* get file extension */
            continue;

        if (strcmp (srchext, ext) == 0) {         /* if extensions match      */
            char newpath[PATH_MAX] = "",          /* char array for newpath   */
                *fn = fn_wext (de->d_name);       /* ptr to filename only     */

            sprintf (newpath, "%s/%s", path, fn); /* create newpath */

            errno = 0;
            if (rename (de->d_name, newpath) == -1) { /* rename/validate file */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: move of '%s' to '%s' failed.\n",
                        de->d_name, newpath);
                /* check errno here */
            }
            else    /* output successful result */
                printf ("moved '%s' to '%s'.\n", de->d_name, newpath);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/** atomic test that directory exists (>=1 success, 0 otherwise)
 *  NOTE: no directory is actually created. fail occurs instead.
 */
int dir_exists (char *d)
{
    int flags = O_DIRECTORY | O_RDONLY;
    int mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
    int fd = open (d, flags, mode);

    if (fd < 0)     /* directory does not exist */
        return 0;
    else if (fd) {  /* directory exists, rtn fd */
        close (fd);
    }

    return fd;
}

/** Separates extension component from full filename string.
 *  Returns pointer following last '.' as extension, NULL otherwise.
 *  Protects against false return of ext followin '.' path.
 *  No memory is allocated, create copy of return to preserve.
 */
char *fn_ext (char *fn)
{
    char *sp = NULL;                /* start pointer */
    char *ext;

    if (!fn) return NULL;
    if ((sp = strrchr (fn, '/')))   /* test for '/' to eliminate '.' in path */
        sp++;
    else
        sp = fn;

    if ((ext = strrchr (sp, '.')))
    {
        if (ext == fn)              /* dot file case */
            return NULL;
        ext++;
    }
    else
        ext = NULL;

    return ext;
}

/** Separates filename component (with extension) from full filename string.
 *  Returns pointer following last '/' filename, full-string otherwise.
 *  No memory is allocated, create copy of return to preserve.
 */
char *fn_wext (char *s)
{
    char *fn;
    if ((fn = strrchr (s, '/')))
        fn++;
    else
        fn = s;

    return fn;
}

/** remove forward slash '/' at end of 'fn' */
char *stripfwd (char *fn)
{
    size_t len = strlen (fn);

    while (len && fn[len - 1] == '/')
        fn[--len] = 0;

    return fn;
}
```

**Example Files in Current Directory**

```
$ l myvideo_*
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_1.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_2.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_3.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_4.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_5.mkv
```

**Empty 'video' Directory**

```
$ l video
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david  4096 Apr 21 21:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 david david 24576 Apr 21 21:46 ..
```

**Compile/Build**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/readdir_rename readdir_rename.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readdir_rename . mkv video
moved 'myvideo_2.mkv' to 'video/myvideo_2.mkv'.
moved 'myvideo_1.mkv' to 'video/myvideo_1.mkv'.
moved 'myvideo_3.mkv' to 'video/myvideo_3.mkv'.
moved 'myvideo_4.mkv' to 'video/myvideo_4.mkv'.
moved 'myvideo_5.mkv' to 'video/myvideo_5.mkv'.
```

**Confirm Move**

```
$ l video
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david  4096 Apr 21 21:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 david david 24576 Apr 21 21:46 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_1.mkv
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_2.mkv
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_3.mkv
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_4.mkv
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 Apr 21 21:46 myvideo_5.mkv
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions. None of it is hard by itself, but there is quite a bit to consider to provide a reasonably robust move (there are many more validations you can add, this is intended as a minimum example).

Answer (score -1):

opendir() is just the first function. It gives you a DIR structure to work with and nothing else. To get the list of files, you need a loop to run readdir(). See for the complete documentation:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Accessing-Directories.html#Accessing-Directories

But using glob() if you can is much easier than opendir(). See:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html

Comment: Sorry i should have made it clear that I already have a loop to run through readdir(), and within each cycle it detects the file type of each entry and uses that file type to move the file into another directory, so the rename() is being called inside of an if statement inside of the readdir() loop.

Comment: If you already have the loop, then you're correctly iterating over the directory. The compilation failure must be caused by some incorrect syntax you're using.